# How to display two slideshows on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, carousel

I'm using this slideshow as an example, which works perfectly fine. There are shared classes between each slideshow which means that when one finishes only then can the next one begin, I need them to be able to work independently of each other, will classes need to be changed.

Here's just one slideshow

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

The problem comes when I add a second, they don't work independently of each other

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {font-style: italic;}

/* Add a blue color to the author */
.author {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<h1>Slideshow 1</h1>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<h1>Slideshow 2</h1>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
  <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
  <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
  <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

I'd rather the script be able to do this than have to change every class name and duplicate every CSS class, how would this be addressed in Vanilla JS only. It loops through the first and then the second is looped through, how can these be treated independently?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't need to change classes, just need to localize the logic to the slides in each `.slide-container`. So rather than grabbing every slide on the page, grab the slide from the first container and treat those separately from the second container. Should only be bit of selector changes and function call differences.

Comment: That sounds an easier approach than duplicating but I don't know how you'd do that @RandyCasburn

Comment: The prezlehammer beat me to it with a good answer for you. You should consider upvoting that answer (as I did) and accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I should do this... But here goes Object Oriented Style of doing things...

1. Create single **Class** for *ALL SLIDES*
2. Create instances of each slide
3. Call functions for the instance you want..
   The thing I edited in your html was the onclick calls for the **Instances(*or objects*)** and I wrapped both slides and dots in a single section div..

Now you have two sections of slides( slide + dots ) working independently..

```js
let slide1 = new CreateSlide(0);
let slide2 = new CreateSlide(1);

function CreateSlide(index) {
    this.slideContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("section")[index];
    this.slideIndex = 1;

    this.plusSlides = function(n) {
        this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
    };
    this.currentSlide = function(n) {
        this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
    };
    this.showSlides = function(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = this.slideContainer.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = this.slideContainer.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
            this.slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            this.slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
    this.showSlides(1);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #f1f1f1f1;
 }
 /* Slides */
        
 .mySlides {
     display: none;
     padding: 80px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 /* Next & previous buttons */
        
 .prev, .next {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: auto;
     margin-top: -30px;
     padding: 16px;
     color: #888;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
     user-select: none;
 }
 /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        
 .next {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 }
 /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        
 .prev:hover, .next:hover {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     color: white;
  }
  /* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
        
  .dot-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #ddd;
  }
  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        
  .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  /* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
        
  .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
  }
  /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
        
  q {
      font-style: italic;
  }
  /* Add a blue color to the author */
        
  .author {
      color: cornflowerblue;
  }
```

```html
    <h1>Slideshow 1</h1>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
                <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
                <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
                <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="slide1.plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="slide1.plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dot-container">
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide1.currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide1.currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide1.currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <h1>Slideshow 2</h1>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
                <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
                <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
                <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="slide2.plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="slide2.plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dot-container">
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide2.currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide2.currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="slide2.currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does work but I don't understand it enough to integrate with what I have, I'm entirely new to JS, I can only change the script as the HTML and CSS are done, I've updated my question with all of what I have though if you could take a look :)

Comment: First is looped through and the second is looped through..? One after another?? Is that independent though??? What do you mean?? And anyways I've not invented some abstract thing here... Just classes.. You have to learn them somehow.. why not now? :D..

Comment: The actual explanation is hard to apply to code you already have, rewriting it entirely isn't really an option. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216988/javascript-functionality-wont-duplicate-across-carousels), it has more clarity.

Comment: Maybe you could do this if only JS is used... preventDefault for every prev and next btns and the dot btns click... And add the above code into your js... After creating every slide like above (you don't have to understand to implement) add the onclick operations to each of their prev next dot btns