# Making multiple carousels on one page functional?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215274/displaying-two-slideshows-on-the-same-page) question here's a fuller sample of the code as the answers in the previous question don't properly integrate and the functionality is then lost. I've changed it enough to the point that it's now a different question, hence the separate posting.

The slideshow works when there's just one, the second one cycles through as it stands currently. I need them to work independently of each other, with changes to the JS only if possible as the HTML and CSS are done already. The HTML may need to be changed but it might be possible to repeat classes and just look up each slideshow via the contents of one of the `DIV` wrappers. I'm just unsure on the best approach or how to do it.

Libraries aren't functional or practical when this is all I need in terms of functionality and I can't do a full rewrite because of the page structure. The script can change but the HTML and CSS can't really.

Anything would be helpful as I'm new to JS so can't understand how to make this work more than once.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("AnalyticsSlide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("webpage-analytics-slider-dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" webpage-analytics-slider-active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " webpage-analytics-slider-active";
}
```

```css
.webpage-analytics-info-tips-module-container-wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.webpage-analytics-info-container {
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 250px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border: solid #FF000D 5px;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.webpage-analytics-tips-studio-container {
    width: 48%;
    min-height: 250px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border: solid #FF000D 5px;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.webpage-analytics-slides-outer {
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.webpage-analytics-slides-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.AnalyticsSlide {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.webpage-analytics-previous-slide, .webpage-analytics-next-slide {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #FF000D;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.webpage-analytics-next-slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.webpage-analytics-previous-slide:hover, .webpage-analytics-next-slide:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #8A0404;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8.5px;
    background: #D2D2D2;
    user-select: none;
    border-top: solid #FF000D 5px;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FF000D;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-active, .webpage-analytics-slider-dot:hover {
    background-color: #8A0404;
}

.webpage-analytics-slide-inner {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="webpage-analytics-info-container">


    <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-outer">

      <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-container">

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 1
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 2
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 3
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 4
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 5
          </div>
        </div>






        <a class="webpage-analytics-previous-slide" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="webpage-analytics-next-slide" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>



        <div class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container">
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot webpage-analytics-slider-active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>





  <div class="webpage-analytics-tips-studio-container">

    <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-outer">

      <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-container">

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 1
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 2
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 3
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 4
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 5
          </div>
        </div>


        <a class="webpage-analytics-previous-slide" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="webpage-analytics-next-slide" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

        <div class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container">
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot webpage-analytics-slider-active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation :** Instead of using variable like `slideIndex`, I have used a data attribute, i.e. `data-slide`. I have made changes in the parameters being passed while the invocation of event handlers. Both the `plusSlide()` function, as well as `currentSlide()` modify the value of data attribute, and call `showSlide()`. The parameter of `showSlide()` is the parent container div of carousal slide being changed. Rest of the code must be easy to understand. Let me know in case you are unable to understand some part.

```js
function plusSlides(el, n) {
  let newEl = el.parentElement;
  newEl.dataset.slide = +(newEl.dataset.slide) + n;
  showSlides(newEl);
}

function currentSlide(el, n) {
  let newEl = el.parentElement.parentElement;
  newEl.dataset.slide = n;
  showSlides(newEl);
}

function showSlides(el) {
  var slides = el.getElementsByClassName("AnalyticsSlide");
  var dots = el.getElementsByClassName("webpage-analytics-slider-dot");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) 
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    dots[i].classList.remove("webpage-analytics-slider-active");
  
  let slide = el.dataset.slide;
  
  if (slide > slides.length)
    el.dataset.slide = 1
  
  else if (slide < 1)
    el.dataset.slide = slides.length;
  
  let slideInd = el.dataset.slide - 1;
  slides[slideInd].style.display = "flex";
  dots[slideInd].classList.add("webpage-analytics-slider-active");
}
```

```css
.webpage-analytics-info-tips-module-container-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.webpage-analytics-info-container {
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid #FF000D 5px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webpage-analytics-tips-studio-container {
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid #FF000D 5px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webpage-analytics-slides-outer {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.webpage-analytics-slides-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.AnalyticsSlide {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.webpage-analytics-previous-slide,
.webpage-analytics-next-slide {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #FF000D;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.webpage-analytics-next-slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.webpage-analytics-previous-slide:hover,
.webpage-analytics-next-slide:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #8A0404;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8.5px;
  background: #D2D2D2;
  user-select: none;
  border-top: solid #FF000D 5px;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FF000D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.webpage-analytics-slider-active,
.webpage-analytics-slider-dot:hover {
  background-color: #8A0404;
}

.webpage-analytics-slide-inner {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.webpage-analytics-slide-inner-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.webpage-analytics-slide-inner-image {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="webpage-analytics-info-tips-module-container-wrap">
  <div class="webpage-analytics-info-container">
    <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-outer">
      <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-container" data-slide="1">

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 1
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 2
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 3
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 4
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 5
          </div>
        </div>


        <a class="webpage-analytics-previous-slide" onclick="plusSlides(this, -1)">❮</a>
        <a class="webpage-analytics-next-slide" onclick="plusSlides(this, 1)">❯</a>

        <div class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container">
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot webpage-analytics-slider-active" onclick="currentSlide(this, 1)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 3)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 4)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 5)"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="webpage-analytics-tips-studio-container">
    <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-outer">
      <div class="webpage-analytics-slides-container" data-slide="1">

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 1
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 2
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 3
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 4
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="AnalyticsSlide" style="display:none;">
          <div class="webpage-analytics-slide-inner">
            Slide 5
          </div>
        </div>


        <a class="webpage-analytics-previous-slide" onclick="plusSlides(this, -1)">❮</a>
        <a class="webpage-analytics-next-slide" onclick="plusSlides(this, 1)">❯</a>

        <div class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot-container">
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot webpage-analytics-slider-active" onclick="currentSlide(this, 1)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 3)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 4)"></span>
          <span class="webpage-analytics-slider-dot" onclick="currentSlide(this, 5)"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried integrating with what I had and it didn't work off the bat so I swapped everything out and it's working perfectly thank you so much.  The extra explanation helped as well as none of the rest of the `HTML` or `CSS` changing I think.